# How to render formatted text field from paragraphs as is in twig?

Tags: views, theming, 8, nodes

I need to render a text (formatted long) field using twig. At this time i am doing the following below. However, i am finding that if i were to add a line break in the text field or apply adding spacing or a horizontal line, the twig filter "raw" removes those attributes. I need assistance to see what I am missing.

I have already set the view mode for field on the content type to default

Twig template (filter used)

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.field_body.value|raw }}
{% endfor %}
```

Expecting
[image]

Actual result
[image]

Comment: You’re using an HTML enabled filter but then using raw. It won’t print. Why do you need full html if you’re going to remove it?

Comment: @Kevin for some reason i can only print it using {{ item.field_body.value|raw }}. if i just print .value then i get everything back but the html is returned as plaint text so when the page render it renders with <p> as if it were a plain text field. What is the appropriate way to print a full html field with all the applied styling in it?

Comment: Leave it as the default? ie delete the custom twig file?

Comment: Or just do an `{{ item.content }}` ?

Comment: @Hudri i have set the view mode for the field as default. I need to use a twig template file to output specific <div> tags so using {{ item.content }} has not worked because  for some reason it does not output as expected (see screenshots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code I'm using inside one of my field templates to output a text field, which is used as an HTML/JS widget input box

```
{% for item in items %}
  <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content['#context'].value|raw }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Should work for you, I guess you'll have to remove the `|raw` filter for your case. (But usually it is not the recommended way to output fields this way.)

Comment: i didn't think to use the #context element. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Never use raw, it **will** hurt you, use this instead

```
{{ {
    '#type': 'processed_text',
    '#text':  item.content['#context'].value,
    '#format': 'rich_text',
} }}
```